# How to record Vanilla Minecraft in higher FPS than the screen?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, recording, framerate

For slowing down video footage, a high frame rate is useful. But if the screen only shows 60 frames per second, even if I set Minecraft and OBS to 120 frames per second, it only records 60 distinct frames per second and then saves every frame twice.

I could use Tickspeed mod or Replay mod, but those don't work in snapshots, very new or very old versions.

So how do I actually record 120 distinct frames per second in Vanilla Minecraft?

I have a Debian and a Windows PC. Answers that work for Debian are preferred.

This question could just as well apply to any program, but I mainly care about slow-motion recordings of Minecraft (and I know that it can generate more than 60 frames per second).

Note that this question is not about performance. In my test, I had 90-120 fps in Minecraft and OBS recorded smoothly, the finished recording was also formatted as 120fps, but it didn't actually have 120 different frames in a second (verified by slowing down video in VLC media player).

Comment: I don't think your game or OBS are the cause of your problem, but rather the OS or your video card driver, as the game merely presents new images, whereas the os/video driver actually applies it. Have you checked your video card settings? Do you have vsync enabled perhaps in your video card settings?

Comment: I don't really have any graphics card settings on Debian. On Windows, I can set "wait for vertical refresh" and "frame rate target control", I can play around with that in a few days (until then a really CPU heavy process is running, so I wouldn't get a smooth video anyway). But what I mainly thought was that there might be a way to get the image of Minecraft directly, before it even gets sent to the screen. I don't really know how this process works, so it might be impossible.

Comment: It's one of the tasks of an os to prevent programs from reading and writing to eachother's memory, because that can be very dangerous. If you want to get the images from minecraft without having to go through the os, you'll have to write and/or use a mod. I found [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/3jhrlj/at_what_framerate_does_windows_run/) and I think it applies to most, if not all oses. I can't say it with 100% certainty, but I think that is why you only get 60 fps.